# Counting a value in one cell

Tags: sql, count

I'm still new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out how to count the values within one cell.
Don't mind my Excel formula I was trying to calculate the data so I wouldn't have to go through SQL.

[image: 1]

This is what I am coming up with, but it is counting the whole column and not the cell.

`SELECT COUNT(Binlocation1) FROM BinLoc`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally you would not calculate the value in a "cell", but rather the "cell" would hold a value that you could query.

Comment: In an inventory perspective, I am trying to keep track of inventory by entering data into Excel then updating SQL. I am testing if I can add more than one value in one cell rather then having to create a whole bunch of columns and enter them in numerically. Hope this gives an better idea of what I'm trying to do. I'm guessing I might just have to create those columns and use a query to filter data and do sum of those data.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I believe OP is trying to count the number of comma-separated values within a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in the Microsoft SQL Server dialect:

```
SELECT
  -- Include any existing columns in the table.
  *,
  -- Calculate a new column: 'BinLocationQuantity'.
  (DATALENGTH(BinLocation1) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(BinLocation1, ', ', ''))) / DATALENGTH(', ') + 1
    AS BinLocationQuantity
FROM BinLoc
```

The idea is to

1. Determine how much the `', '` separator contributes to the length of the text in the `BinLocation1` field.  We do this by taking the difference between **(a)** the length of the field, and **(b)** the length of the field  when all occurrences of the separator are removed ([`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)d with the empty `''` string).  Here we use [`DATALENGTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) rather than [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql), to avoid confusion over whitespace.
2. Determine how *many* such separators there are.  We do this by taking the total length (above) contributed by all the separators, and then dividing it by the length of a single separator: `DATALENGTH(', ')`.
3. Extrapolate how many values are in the `BinLocation1` text. We do this by adding `1` to the number (above) of separators:

```
--     1       2       3       4          N + 1
   'value1, value2, value3, value4, ..., valueN'
--        ^^      ^^      ^^           ^^
--         1       2       3            N
```

## Warning

The assumption must hold that each `BinLocation1` text is of the form

```
'value1, value2, value3, value4'
```

and has neither any missing separators

```
'value1 value2, value3value4'
--     ^              ^
```

nor any extra separators:

```
  ', value1, value2, , value3, value4, '
-- ^^                ^^              ^^
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jvang No problem!  I updated the table name to `BinLoc`, so if you're running that SQL dialect, you should be able to use the query as is.

Comment: @Jvang Does the SQL work for you?

Comment: Yes, the query does work for me.

Comment: @Jvang Glad to hear it!  If this addressed your problem, kindly [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Thank you, @Jvang!